# UDP client in C: Not idea why it doesn't work

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

We are supposed to write a simple UDP client for a Networking class, the code below is our approach. We followed several examples pretty closely, yet the client doesn't produce a response. We have a server that logs its incoming messages, but no messages from our client show up.

We have tried do debug this for several hours now, but to no avail. If someone could point us into the right direction we'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define MAX 1024


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int sockfd, actualSize;
    char buf[MAX];
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;

    if (getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &res) != 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {

        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("Please enter a message: ");
            fgets(buf, MAX, stdin);

            if (sendto(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                perror("Error while sending to server");
                exit(1);
            }

            if ((actualSize = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAX-1, 0, p->ai_addr, &(p->ai_addrlen))) == -1) {
                perror("recv");
                exit(1);
            }
            buf[actualSize] = '\0';

            break;
        }

    }

    printf ("%s\n", buf);
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: UDP doesn't have clients. Applications may have clients.

Comment: 1) Can you ping the server? 2) Can you talk to the server via netcat? 3) Have you used wireshark or some other packet sniffer to see if your packets are making it to the wire? There's a lot of variables in network communication, using established tools and network analyzers helps isolate problems.

Comment: @yano We are actually using netcat via `echo "hello world" | netcat -ul <port>`. We've also tried it with a simple Python server (which works with a Python client), with the same result.

Comment: you're saying netcat can't talk to the server? the `l` option for netcat tells it to listen. Which side is supposed to initiate the communication?

Comment: No, netcat is the server (one of them).

Comment: can two netcats talk to each other? What I'm getting at is there may be a firewall or AV or something blocking the communication.

Comment: Have you considered asking specifically for an IPv4 (respectively IPv6, as appropriate) address by setting `ai_family = AF_INET` (or `AF_INET6`) in your `getaddrinfo()` hints?

Comment: Ok, I have tried to get two netcats talking to each other like this: `echo "hello world" | netcat -ul 12000` and `echo "test" | netcat -u localhost 12000`. The result is `read(net): Connection refused` on the client side. However, netcat + Python server or Python server + client work fine on the same port. i'm on a freshly installed macOS 10.12.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Wow, that did the trick.Thank you and thanks @ yano.

Comment: `..., &(p->ai_addrlen)` is suspect